# How to draw a zip-code level Choropleth map

Tags: python, plotly

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks as follows:

```
user_id   zip_code    city              county        state
0001      10021       New York          New York      NY
0002      10003       New York          New York      NY
0003      06831       Greenwich         Fairfield     CT
0004      33172       Miami             Miami-Dade    FL
0005      07417       Franklin Lakes    Bergen        NJ
```

I'm trying to plot a ***zip-code*** level choropleth using the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import requests

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)


fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    geojson= counties,
                    locations='fips', 
                    locationmode="USA-states", 
                    scope="usa",
                    color='user_id',
                    color_continuous_scale="blues",
                    )

fig.show()
```

But, the map is rendering as blank.

How do I render a ***zip-code level*** choropleth?

Answer (score 4):

The reason it is not displayed is because the geojson file you are using does not have the zip code data. Therefore, it is necessary to prepare a geojson file with zip codes. As an example, I created a graph with sample data from [here](https://github.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON). Depending on your data, if you want to handle zip codes for the entire US, the number of data will be huge and will affect the performance.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import requests

# Nevada Zip code
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpenDataDE/State-zip-code-GeoJSON/master/nv_nevada_zip_codes_geo.min.json'
with urlopen(url) as response:
    nv_zip_json = json.load(response)

zip_code = []
for i in range(len(nv_zip_json['features'])):
    code = nv_zip_json['features'][i]['properties']['ZCTA5CE10']
    zip_code.append(code)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'zip_code': zip_code, 'value': np.random.randint(0,30, len(nv_zip_json['features']))})
df['zip_code'] = df['zip_code'].astype(str)

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    geojson= nv_zip_json,
                    locations='zip_code',
                    featureidkey="properties.ZCTA5CE10",
                    color='value',
                    color_continuous_scale="blues",
                    projection="mercator",
                    )

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

fig.show()
```

[image]

To draw a map by county using the current data, the following code can be used.

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    geojson= counties,
                    locations='county',
                    featureidkey="properties.NAME",
                    scope="usa",
                    color='user_id',
                    color_continuous_scale="blues",
                    )

fig.show()
```

[image]